# AJAX submit button disabling after one request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm building a Rails app and have a Javascript form using AJAX and JQUERY. The form is submitting correctly and the content is injecting into the DOM just fine but once this happens the submit button greys out and a new request cannot be submitted until I refresh the page.

I compared the code to a previous app I built and it's identical. The only difference I can see is that the previous app was built with Rails '4.2.10' and this new one uses Rails '5.2.3'

```js
$('#new_order').on('submit', function(e) {
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize())
   .done(function(response) {
    let o = new Order(response)
    $('#order_address').val("")
    $('order_special_instructions').val("")
    $('#orders').append(o.format())
  }).error(function() {
    alert('error')
  })
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: I recommend moving `e.preventDefault()` to the first statement.

Comment: There must be some other event handler somewhere that greys it out or if `#orders` is containing the button, perhaps the server sets it to disabled

Comment: Is there any validation rules on the form ? Can you share the code of the view ?

Comment: I haven't added any other even handlers. This is my first Stack Overflow question, whats the best way to add more code?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think the problem is you use `e.preventDefault()` when you submit, but you didn't replace this form with new content. So this form will stay in submitting status.

Since you are using Rails 5.2, I'll recommend to use `form_with` instead of jQuery ajax. It's default as ajax request in Rails way and you just have to render partial you want in `create.js.erb`.

It will be something like this:

`orders/_form.erb`

```
<%= form_with model: Order.new, url: orders_path do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

And your `create.js.erb`

```
let orderForm = "<%= j(render('orders/form')) >";
$('#new_order').html(orderForm);
$('#order_address').val("")
$('order_special_instructions').val("")

let order = "<%= j(render('orders/order')) >"
$('#orders').append(order)
```

And don't forget to include rails-ujs in your assets pipeline, or import it in case you use webpacker.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the form with new content the way I have it now or with rails 5 is the form_with the only way to do this?

Comment: You can cancel the `e.preventDefault()` first. add `$(this).unbind('submit')` to unbind submit event after the request end. It will make form back to normal. And replace content in your jQuery

Comment: I'm not having any success with the unbind and removing the preventDefault allows the page to refresh which kind of defeats the purpose of using AJAX. Am I missing something? Sorry, I'm still a pretty novice coder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Rails 5 automatically disables the submit button after submitting a request. I had to add

data: { disable_with: false }

to my submit button in my view.